# Convert RDD to DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am not able to convert the RDD data into Dataframe in pyspark.

Here is the code that I have written.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType, Row
from pyspark.sql import *
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("pyspark") \
        .master("local[3]") \
        .getOrCreate()  
empdata = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/empdatarevised.txt").map(lambda x: x.split(","))        
schema = StructType([
        StructField("eid",IntegerType(),True),
        StructField("ename",StringType(),True),
        StructField("edept",StringType(),True),
        StructField("esal", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("revsal", DoubleType(), True),
        ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=empdata,schema=schema)
df.show()
```

I am getting the error

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 7) (ip-10-172-239-64.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: field eid: IntegerType can not accept object '100' in type <class 'str'>'. Full traceback below:

I know this can be done by `spark.read.format("csv").load("file.txt")`, but my intension is to convert RDD to Dataframe with StructType.

Seeking your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is unable to convert the strings to integers/doubles when you create a dataframe from an RDD. You can change the type of the entries in the RDD explicitly, e.g.

```
empdata = (sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/empdatarevised.txt")
             .map(lambda x: x.split(","))
             .map(lambda x: [int(x[0]), x[1], x[2], int(x[3]), float(x[4])])
          )

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=empdata,schema=schema)
```